# Disable Google Chrome Quicksearch

Tags: google-chrome

I'm currently using Google Chrome and I run into a problem searching:

Whenever I type something like "Google Chrome" into the address bar, I mean to say, "Search for Google Chrome". However, Chrome by default thinks I'm asking it to Google *just* the word Chrome.

Any way to disable this, just for the word Google?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know this is old, but if anyone is still running into this, you can disable it in current versions of Chrome:

1. Go to Chrome Settings (navigate to `chrome://settings` or click **Options** in the menu)
2. On the *Basic* tab, in the *Search* section, click the **Manage Search Engines** button
3. Under *Other Search Engines*, remove or rename the **Google Quicksearch** entry

Comment: this is the correct answer to the question.  Thanks.  This has been really annoying me for the past few months but too lazy to find out how to turn this off.

Comment: Still works today, though the interface doesn't use tabs anymore.

Comment: @Mzzzzzz This answer is no longer valid. Instead you need to go to Settings > You and google > Sync and google services > Disable "Autocomplete searches and URLs"

Answer (score 6):

I could think of two methods:

## Explicit search

The address bar can be put into "search mode" by one of the following:

- Ctrl + K
- Type "?" as first character

Everything thereafter will be searched for.

## Change Google keyword

What you describe is usage of keywords, they used to make a quick search using another search engine. For example I use "wp Trees" to search for trees on wikipedia and "ud Tree" to search UrbanDictionary for the same.

In your case "Google" is the keyword for search using google. Change it in Settins->Basic(first Tab), find the header Search, click on the "Manage" button and you will be presented with a list of search engines to edit.

You can see that the keyword is in effect after typing the keyword, space and the first letter in your search, the addressbar left side changes to a blue frame around the search engine.

Answer (score 4):

You can put it in quotes:

> "Google Chrome"

Put chrome first (it's the same query):

> Chrome Google

Or use the + operator to require the term:

> +Google Chrome

Comment: Does that mean there's no way to disable it without typing extra?

Comment: /reordering? I'd like to update it if there's a setting available.

Comment: @Reckage - I'm not aware of any setting for this, but then I haven't dug that deep to find one.  If someone else posts such a setting, that's probably a _better_ answer.  But failing that, I think this is probably the best you can.