# How do I stop Chrome from hijacking the word "google" in my searches?

Tags: google-chrome, search

Several months ago Google Chrome release the most annoying update. Anytime you type the word "google" at the beginning of a search (in the address bar), it hijacks that word and removes it from your search. For example, if I want to search for "google inbox" or "google docs", it changes my search to [Google:] "inbox".

[Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/triAs.png)

Clearly this feature was designed for very dumb users who think they need to instruct the browser to "google" something rather than just typing their search phrase. I am not a dumb users and do not want the browser hijacking my searches.

I find this endlessly frustrating and cannot for the life of me figure out how to turn this off. Any ideas?

Comment: This question has been answered before: https://superuser.com/questions/168319/disable-google-chrome-quicksearch

Answer (score 0):

Use the Boolean operator `" "` . For example `"google"`. This will force the search engine to include that string in the search.